# Javascript Split String at First Numeric

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a UK postcode string to only include the initial letters.  For example, 'AA1 2BB' would become 'AA.'

I was thinking something like the below.

```
var postcode = 'AA1 2BB';
var postcodePrefix = postcode.split([0-9])[0];
```

This does not actually work, but can someone help me out with the syntax?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `postcode.split(/[0-9]/)[0];` maybe?

Comment: Do you want postcodePrefix[1] to contain '1 2BB' or ' 2BB' or does it matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var postcode = 'AA1 2BB';
var postcodePrefix =postcode.split(/[0-9]/)[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use a regex to simply find all alphabetic characters that occur at the beginning of the string:

```
var postcode = 'AA1 2BB';
var postcodePrefix = postcode.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+/);
```

If you want *any* initial characters that are non numeric, you could use:

```
var postcodePrefix = postcode.match(/^[^0-9]+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

"AA1 2BB".split(/[0-9]/)[0];
```

or

```
"AA1 2BB".split(/\d/)[0];
```

Comment: Upvote for `\d` - idk why people use `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = postcode.match(/([^\d]*)/);
if (m) {
   var prefix = m[0];
}
```